# Sync between laptop and PC for eclipse projects

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, git

I work on eclipse IDE mainly for php and java. I own a PC and a laptop both of which I need to use for coding. Now how do i sync code ad resources between two instances of eclipse between these two I think SVN and git are overkill for this. I own a portable USB drive. Is there some nice way to sync these two seamlessly?

Btw I dont need a dynamic sync. I wont be working on both simultaneously. Ill probably work on my comp. Them sync it with laptop and continue working there when im out and then sync with pc when im back..

Comment: git is not overkill.  It works quite nicely on e.g. an USB-key, but is perhaps not optimal for a Windows programmer.

Comment: If you want optimal source control for Windows on a USB key, Mercurial works much better.

Comment: actually im just exporting and importing projects from eclipse. THis is exactly what i needed :) Thanks for ur help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, source control might be a pretty good solution here.

In particular, using a [distributed source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) could be a pretty good route, because they both don't require setting up a Subversion server (one can create a repo right from Eclipse! -- see below regarding plugins), and merging between repositories are very easy.

To make matters easier, that there are plugins available for Eclipse which integrates with git (e.g. [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)) and Mercurial (e.g. MercurialEclipse). Both are easily installable using the [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) feature in Eclipse Helios (3.6).

If you're not using source control, might as well make this an opportunity to start using one! :)

Comment: Source control IS a good idea. Read this: http://cam.ly/blog/2010/12/code-fearlessly/ <- Great helper for building stuff, knowing that what you delete is still there.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to use source control (which is useful, I use mercurial), try DropBox, or Windows Live Mesh. Both can sync over LAN without an internet connection, AFAIK. (Definitely DropBox, anyway)

Both are free.

(P.S. if you're interested in checking out DropBox, use this link, and we'll both get extra free storage space https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTkxNzM4MjU5?src=global0)

Comment: Agreed. I need to organize my folder a little better though :P

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that using SVN in your case is an overkill. You can setup either laptop or desktop as SVN server and both instances of eclipse as SVN clients. Besides sync you will get added benefits of having change log, ability to roll back and all other bells and whistles of a source code repository.